# How do you set a button as highlighted on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do you set an iPhone UIButton to the selected state, i.e. where it is blue highlighted?

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend for simple questions like this you start by looking at the documentation provided by apple. Every class has a reference document which should be your first port of call.

[UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Granted UIButton's documentation does not actually cover the `selected` property but that is where you check the documentation for the classes it inherits from.

Inherits from [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) : UIView : UIResponder : NSObject

And in this case it is UIControl that has the property you are looking for.

```
myButton.selected = YES;
```

Comment: But I did check the documentation and I did use that line of code but it didn't work.  So I presumed there was some kind of limitation?

Comment: As a little more background, there is a second thread operating in the background which is communicating across a stream.  So i think the issue is updating the GUI, even though it is the main thread which picks up the button press event, I can't seem to hold the button in a pressed state (is that the same as selected?)